# Execute string comma character ',' as code

Tags: javascript, eval, decode, execution

I have this code block:

```
var comma_decoded = window.btoa(',');
var comma_encoded = window.atob(comma_decoded);

var log = eval(comma_encoded);

var x = 1 log y = 2;

console.log(x + ' ' + y);
```

but, I can't execute ',' character as code.

I need '1 2' output, so log variable must work like comma (,)

Thank you.

Comment: `x = 1 log y = 2` will only ever mean `x = 1 log y = 2` and will always be nonsensical. If anything you'll want to `eval` that entire thing as "dynamic code". Though I really fail to see the point…

Comment: It looks like you may want to consider using a template language rather than raw JavaScript. Or another language altogether.

Comment: Yeah, that's completely not how that works or how it was ever intended to work. What are you actually trying to do? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: This sounds like a massive [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)...

Comment: I just need, execute comma (,) as code when not use comma character, because deleting from back-end.

Comment: In your example what should the console log output?

Comment: This question makes no sense. You could do `eval("var x = 1" + comma_encoded + "y = 2;")` which is legal, but if you are doing that you are probably doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: The need to use `eval()` usually indicates an issue with the structure of the application, since the amount of valid use cases where you can't avoid eval() is very small. So please describe what this function will do and why you chose eval() over anything else: `new Function( 'var x = 1' + comma_encoded + 'y = 2; )()` or `var [ x, y ] = JSON.parse( '[ 1, 2 ]' );`, etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, you cannot use variables as operators or language-specific tokens.